# JQuery ScrollTop scrolling too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wanting to create basically a full page background image that, once the user clicks (anywhere), scrolls down to the remaining content and then hides itself.  Initially, there would be no scrollbar, then once the click>scrolltop has taken place, and the background div hidden, the scrollbar appears by removing the overflow-hidden class.

My problem is that when I use the scrolltop by itself, the page does scroll directly to the element I've selected, but when I then add in the javascript code to hide the initial introduction div (on which the user clicks), the page jumps down far past the ScrollTop point.

I've included my JSFiddle link here, if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: You didn't include a jsfiddle link - also please post the code in question into the question

Comment: Jesus... My mistake.  https://jsfiddle.net/philippenewman/6kv90r4m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: none` is changing the height of `.intro` to 0, so you have two options:

Change the CSS for `.hidden` to use `visibility: hidden`

or

Change the first parameter of `.animate` to take into account the height of `.intro`: `$(".one").offset().top - $(".intro").height()`

I'd also suggest putting the `removeClass` and `addClass` calls in a callback function, rather than using `.delay()`:

**Example with option 2 + callback usage:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".intro").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".one").offset().top - $(".intro").height()
    }, 700, function() {
      $("body").removeClass("bleh");
      $(".intro").addClass("hidden");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I see the difference.  Thanks much!  It still winds up scrolling about... 10px (approximately) past the .one div though.  Is there some padding or something I'm not seeing here?

Comment: Inspecting it in Chrome DevTools - it seems like there's a weird top margin being added to the `html` element, but it's not showing up as margin or padding, and it doesn't affect the `body`. Might just be because of the tool's viewer window loading the content in an iframe. I tried JSBIn also, and see the same result.

Comment: We're all doomed....  I'll keep playing around with it.  I get your point with the negative modifer to the offset though.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Btw, I discovered the reason for the weird little 10px offset.  It was margin applied to the H1 (or P, or whatever text I had in there).  Not sure why it would push the margin beyond the edge of the container div, but that's what it were.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful? After adding the `hidden` class you can scroll to the top of the `one` div.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".intro").on("click", function(){
    $("body").removeClass("bleh");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop : $(".one").offset().top 
    }, function(){

      $(".intro").addClass("hidden")
      $(document).scrollTop(0)

    })
  })
})
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.bleh{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;

}
.intro{
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%; 

}


.one {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}
.three {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}

.four {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="bleh">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Click anywhere to scroll down to main content</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="one">
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="two">
        
    </div>
        <div class="three">
        
    </div>
        <div class="four">
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah!  Yes!  Perfect.  As I had it, with J. Titus' comment about the offset to the ScrollTop, it worked, but in that order there was no scroll effect as I was firing all three at the same time.  With your solution, they all fire in a better order than I had them, so it actually scrolls, then hides the intro div.  Thank you!   Well done